# How to sort javascript object array by element.name

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, sorting, prototypejs

I am try to write some validation script using javascript and prototype.

What I want to do is to loop through all the elements of a form and validate each answer.  My code works, BUT the array of DOM elements is unsorted.  I would like to sort the elements by their ID.

Here is the my code, which works fine if I comment-out elem.sort(zelementsort);

```
function zelementsort(a,b) {
    if (a.name > b.name)
        return -1;
    else if (b.name > a.name)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}   

var elem = document.getElementById('myform').elements;
elem.sort(zelementsort);

for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
     alert("Name = " + elem[i].name);

}
```

I wonder if the problem might be that some of the elements do not have names.  Anyone have another simpler way of sorting an array of DOM elements by their .name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$$('#myForm *[name]').sortBy(function(el){ return el.name; });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly

var elem = $$('#myForm *[name]').sortBy(function(el){ return el.name; });

Answer (score 1):

This is because `sort()` is not a method of the `DomElementList` you retrieve with `.elements`.

The nice thing is that you can apply the `Array.sort` method to your `DomElementList` using a Javascript trick.

Then, you just have to append the nodes again in the DOM, they won't be duplicated but moved.

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myform'),
    elem = myform.elements;

// call the Array.sort() method on our DomElementList
Array.prototype.sort.call(elem, function()
{
    if (a.name > b.name)
        return -1;
    else if (b.name > a.name)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
});

for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
     myform.appendChild(elem[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation without **if** based on native js [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function.

```
elements.sort(function(a, b) { return 2 * (a.name > b.name) - 1; })
```

Comment: Great, it worked real fine!
Thank you for the solution! Descending order: `elements.sort(function(a, b) { return 2 * (a.name < b.name) - 1; })`