# What does [ ] stand for?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found this piece of code on StackOverflow:

```
[].sort.call(data, function (a, b) {})
```

Is `[]` a shorthand for "sort data values and then make an array with the same name"?

Comment: probably need some more context for this line of code. As it stands right now it's not even valid javascript.

Comment: That simply initializes an empty array `[]`. It's also known as an array literal. See this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it) for more details...

Comment: [] is an array and it is used here to call the sort on data that is not an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[]` is just array literal. It's an empty array, because it doesn't contain any elements. In this context it's a shortcut to `Array.prototype`.

This code basically allows you to use `Array.prototype.sort()` method even on values which are not arrays, for example `arguments`.

Further explanation:

```
[] // Array literal. Creates an empty array.
  .sort // Array.prototype.sort function.
  .call( // Function.prototype.call function
    data, // Context (this) passed to sort function
    function (a, b) {} // Sorting function
  )
```

Assuming that you have an array-like object, like this:

```
var obj = {0: "b", 1: "c", 2: "a", length: 3};
```

It's array-like, because it has numeric keys and `length` property. However, you can't just call `.sort()` method on it, because `Object.prototype` doesn't have such method. You can instead call `Array.prototype.sort()` in context of your object. That's exactly what `Function.prototype.call()` method is for. The first argument of `.call()` method is context passed to the function, and the rest are arguments passed to the function. For example:

```
Array.prototype.sort.call(obj)
```

returns sorted object, because `Array.prototype.sort` behaves like it was `obj` method.

Note that using `Array.prototype` is generally better practice than using array literal, because it's more explicit.

See also:

- [`Function.prototype.call()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)
- [Array.prototype.sort.apply( someArray, args ) vs someArray.sort.apply( someArray, args )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156769/array-prototype-sort-apply-somearray-args-vs-somearray-sort-apply-somearray)
- [How to sort javascript object array by element.name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424196/how-to-sort-javascript-object-array-by-element-name)
- [What is array literal notation in javascript and when should you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it)